# Check if AddMember method has failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing code in VBA (in Excel) that puts Outlook contacts into a distribution list.

It works so far, but error handling in case the contact does not exist is not working. MS says

> If the specified recipient is not valid, the AddMember method will
>   fail.

So how do you notice if the method fails?

```
Public Function olAddContactToList(ByVal sLastName As String, _
  Optional ByVal sFirstName As String, _
  Optional ByVal sGroup As String) As Boolean

  Dim oOutlook As Object    ' Outlook.Application
  Dim oNameSpace As Object  ' Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim oMAPIFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim oContact As Object    ' Outlook.ContactItem
  Dim oList As Object       ' Outlook.DistListItem
  Dim oMail As Object       ' Outlook.MailItem
  Dim oRecip As Object      ' Outlook.Recipient

  Const olFolderContacts = 10

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set oMAPIFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
  Set oList = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items(sGroup)

 'Adds a member to a new distribution list
 Set oMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 'Create recipient for distlist
 Set oRecip = oOutlook.Session.CreateRecipient(sFirstName & " " & sLastName)

 oRecip.Resolve

 oList.AddMember oRecip

 oList.Save
 olAddContactToList = True

ErrHandler:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Fehler beim Hinzufügen des Outlook-Kontakts zu einer Liste." & vbCrLf & _
      CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly

    olAddContactToList = False
  End If

  Set oContact = Nothing
  Set oMAPIFolder = Nothing
  Set oNameSpace = Nothing
  Set oOutlook = Nothing
  Set oList = Nothing
  Set oMail = Nothing
  Set oRecip = Nothing

End Function
```

I have tried

```
Dim AddCheck As Long
AddCheck = oList.AddMember(oRecip)
```

but `AddCheck` stays 0 irrespective of the contact existing and being successfully added to the list or not existing and failing to be added.

Comment: If the method fails, execution should be jumping to the `ErrHandler` label, and a `MsgBox` should display the error. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: That's not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result of `Recipient.Resolve` is either `True` or `False` (says [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve)), you should check that.
Otherwise you only have a firstname and lastname, but not a full email address:

```
If Not oRecip.Resolve Then
    ' no resulting email address
Else
    ' email address found, go further
End If
```

As `DistListItem.AddMember` even raises no error, if you try to add a simple phone number string (just doesn't add it), I suggest to compare `DistListItem.MemberCount` (oList.MemberCount in your code) additionally before and after trying to add a new member.

By that you`ll either get an error or an unchanged member count, if something went wrong, and can do further checks.

Comment: Ok thanks, that solves my problem if a contact doesn't exist. But still I wonder why the `AddMember` method didn't fail with an invalid recipient (or at least its failing doesn't lead to a jump to the `ErrHandler`). So what will happen if the method fails for some other reason?

Comment: @Nyuki seems your definition of "fails" is different than that of `AddMember`.

Comment: Humm, so my question should be more general: how can I make sure that I will be alarmed if the task I was going to get performed (adding a contact to a distribution list) has not been performed?

Comment: I suggest to compare `MemberCount` additionally to error handling. If that works for you, please consider to mark it as answer as explained here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).